# Is it possible to increment a component property value inside *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to increment a class property inside ngFor for each iteration by 1.Let me know if there is a way.Thanks in advance.

**Component Class:**

```
class AA
   {      
  property:number = 0;
   }
```

**Template:**

```
 <div *ngFor = "let sample of samples">
    //increment property here
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index`

```
 <div *ngFor = "let sample of samples;let i = index">
    <span [class]="'opacity-'+(i+1)">value {{i+1}}</span>
    <button (click)="property = (i+1)">Set Selected Item</button>
 </div>
Selected Item : {{property}}
```

Comment: how property value is going to be incremented inside div ?

Comment: can you give an example like ngClass ??

Comment: I just want to increment property value. But no ngClass and stuff is involved.Thank you

Comment: What kind of value ?

Comment: its just a class property value..say x : number = 0;

Comment: what about a button when you click the button set the value to property of the class is this what you want @AsridhKumar

Comment: @ Muhammed Albarmawi  ..No i just want to increment a component property value in ngFor .No ngClass or button etc are involved

Comment: like this {{property = (i+1)}} but property will get the last index or increment like this {{property += (i+1)}} @AsridhKumar

Comment: ..how to increment the property is fine..but i want to know where in ngFor can we increment a direct component property??

Comment: Wow, that was easy!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function in your class and call it into the ngfor bloc

```js
class AA
   {      
  property:number = 0;
  
  function increment_property(): void{
    this.property++;
  }
   }
```

```html
<div *ngFor = "let sample of samples">
    {{ increment_property() }}
 </div>
```